# Infinite Scroll for iPhone

Tags: jquery, iphone, scroll, infinite-scroll

I am using the below to trigger an inifinite scroll and fire an Ajax request.  This works fine on desktop and iPad browsers but not on iPhone.  What am I missing?

```
//Ajax
var page = 1;    
$(window).scroll(function() {

        if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {

            page++;

            var data = {
                page_num : page
            };

            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : "data.php",
                data : data,
                success : function(res) {
                    $(".thumbnails").append(res);
                }
            });

        }

    });
```

Comment: Try use [some plugin](http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2012/05/26/10-aggressively-used-jquery-infinite-scroll-plugins-for-endless-paging/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This solved it:

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 60) {
```